# Experimenting with high concurrent connection server

Tags: server

I am trying to build a server which can handle as many concurrent connections as possible. (100k at least, for a start)

Right now, when i test it through LAN, it can go up to 50k+ concurrent connections easily (did not test more yet). However when I test it from outside my LAN, it never goes beyond about 8k...

To be more precise, when going past 8k, the first sockets no longer receive any data, as if the new ones replaced them...

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

I have done some research, and it seems, although it isn't clear, that routers/modems may have a limited amount of supported concurrent connections, is that true?
If so, and if that's my problem, do I have to get one that can support more? Or get rid of it somehow?

Comment: Allow me one question: what kind of server do you build and what justifies not using one already available ? Is this something "new" or do you do this with the purpose of learning ? I suppose you have a software solution ? Or is this a hardware problem ? If software: which programming language ? operating system run on ? Is your LAN simply localhost or really a computer-to-computer connection ? You see: lots of questions arise ;-)

Comment: I'm doing this only for the purpose of learning for now. I programmed the server in Java. The server doesn't do anything appart from accepting connections and checking for incoming data. Clients sends a "beat" every 5 seconds to see if they're still connected. I tested the server both via localhost and from another pc in the same LAN, both work fine with 50k+ clients. I run on Win 7. I guess I should've given alot more detail :P